# Failed To import XML in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have created e-Commerce WordPress website using woo-commerce. After completing my website I export all site data including (posts, comments, products, pictures) etc.
But now when I import my data into another WordPress site it shows an error!
[Here is Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5M32.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to install all the plugins that where installed. It fails to import products as WooCommerce is not installed